# Android - Fragment not being removed from the stack with popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making a simple app like this:

[image]

The button "Push Fragment" replaces the current fragment 
with a new one.
The button "Pop Fragment" should remove a fragment from the stack.

This is the code for the activity:

```
public class ActivityWithMenu extends Activity{
    private WVFragment wvFragment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_menu);

        wvFragment = (WVFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.wv_fragment);

        Button btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPopFragment);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    Log.i("FRAGMENT_EXAMPLE", "will pop the current fragment");
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnPush = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPushFragment);
        btnPush.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.wv_fragment, wvFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

                WebView wv = (WebView)wvFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
                wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the activity_with_menu view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Pop Fragment"
      android:id="@+id/btnPopFragment" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     ></Button>
   <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Push Fragment"
      android:id="@+id/btnPushFragment" 
      android:layout_below="@+id/btnPopFragment"
     ></Button>
   <fragment 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/btnPushFragment"
       android:id="@+id/wv_fragment"
       class="com.lucasdev.baseactivitydemo.WVFragment"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Fragment:

```
public class WVFragment extends Fragment{
    private View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wv_fragment, container, false);

        WebView wv = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

        return view;
    }
}
```

and this is the fragment view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong since the "Pop Fragment" is not removing
any fragment after a new one is pushed.

But I know the popBackStack() is called since the messages is always printed in the
console.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your XMLs plz

Comment: @KanakSony, I added the layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a new `Fragment` each time you click on Push.

```
fragment = new WVFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.wv_fragment, fragment );
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

WebView wv = (WebView)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Because if you add the same (instance) of the Fragment, you don't have an another.

Comment: thanks @Kevinrob, I did exactly what you suggested but the problem persists

Comment: and if you change `replace` by `add`?

Comment: I just replace the call to replace by add. The message is still displayed in the console but the fragment is not removed yet

Comment: thanks again Kevin. I tried yor edited answer but if I instantiate WVFragment that way, I get a BullPointerException in this line WebView wv = (WebView)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.webview); although I think you are right

Comment: Okay, so you have to do that initialisation in onCreateView. Why do you do this here and in onCreateView?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `popBackStack()` to pop the current Fragment, just use the native BackButton method of the activity.

**example:**

```
 Button btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPopFragment);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ActivityWithMenu.this.onBackPressed();

        }
    });
```

**onBackPressed** will have this same functionality that you desire for popping the Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

First, try removing your fragment from XML and keep an empty container there:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Pop Fragment"
      android:id="@+id/btnPopFragment" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     ></Button>
   <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Push Fragment"
      android:id="@+id/btnPushFragment" 
      android:layout_below="@+id/btnPopFragment"
     ></Button>
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and Then you need to add your Fragment i.e. com.lucasdev.baseactivitydemo.WVFragment fragment from code, i.e. in `onClick()` of your btnPush.

Let me know, if still issue persists.